# Who provides the default constructor in Java? Compiler or JVM?

Tags: java, constructor, jvm, default-constructor

Is the constructor added at run-time or compile time?(I guess it is compile time).
I need some in depth explanation please, at JVM architecture level.

I read various articles.. some says compiler.. and others say JVM. I want to be very much sure(proofs will help a lot).

Sorry if the question is stupid(am still digesting the terminologies)!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javap` decompiler to take a look at a simple class. You will see the compiler adds the constructor.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf page 118:  " ... **compiler-generated methods** ..., namely the instance initialization method representing a
**default constructor of the Java programming language (§2.9)**".

Comment: In practice the `javac` compiler adds this to the byte code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a formal reference, the nature of the *default constructor* is explained in both:

- The Java Language Specification (JLS), section [8.8.9 Default Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)
- The Java Virtual Machine Specification, section [2.12 Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/Concepts.doc.html#16411).

Alternatively, if you're using Oracle JDK or OpenJDK, you could easily demonstrate this behavior to verify that it is the compiler the one that does all the magic.

All you need to do is to use the Java decompiler tool that comes with your JDK to see what bytecodes are being generated in your class files.

You should see an executable named `javap` under `$JDK_HOME/bin/`

If you had a simple file like `Demo.java` containing just one class, e.g.

```
public class Demo {}
```

And you compile it using the command `javac Demo.java`, and then you run the decompiler using `javap -c Demo`, the output should say something like:

```
Compiled from "Demo.java"
public class Demo {
  public Demo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

Which demonstrates that it is the compiler which adds the default constructor, since it was not in your source code but it is indeed in your compiled class file.

You will also notice that the constructor access level matches that of the class for which it was generated. So, if you do

```
public class Demo { 
  protected static class Other {}
}
```

And you compile that, and then do a `javap -c Demo.Other` you get

```
public class Demo$Other {
  protected Demo$Other();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

Once more, demonstrating that the compiler adds a default constructor matching the accessibility of the class for which it was generated as the specifications above say it should do.

Answer (score 11):

From the Java Tutorial from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. **The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.** This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor.

Comment: You should consider adding emphasis to the "compiler", which answers the question.